# What is Eclipse's Declaration View used for?

Tags: java, eclipse

We have some class files with globs of redundant code.  I've been looking for a view in Eclipse which allows you to limit your editor to just a single method, similar to Module View button in VB6, for those of you who know what I mean.  The need for this is to make it easier to search for a string and have the search limited to only the code within the method I care about.  (It's also a nice feature for editing large globs of code, to make sure I am not accidentally adding the code to a different large method with redundant code.)

I thought the Declaration View would do this, but this view neither allows search nor editing.  This leads to a 2-part question:

a. This there any view in Eclipse that can be used as described above?

b. Given Declaration View's limitations, what is it useful for?  (The only link I found directly Declaration View [Hands On Eclipse](http://handsoneclipse.wordpress.com/tag/view/) didn't make much sense to me.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**a)** Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor` and select `Show only selected Java element`.

I believe that's what you want :) This way you can use the `Outline View` to navigate throughout the members of the class.

**b)** The `Declaration View` is just a quick reference about:

- The line you declared the variable, if your cursor is at one.
- The code of the Type/Method/Annotation/etc., if your cursor is at one of them

Comment: AFAIK Not based on javadoc. Javadoc has another panel.

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that... My mistake.

Comment: Perfectly answered! Is there any way to toggle Selected Java element on/off without modifying preferences?

Comment: I don't know... it's kind of a "hidden feature". But well, with `Eclipse Juno`, you can use the `Quick Access` field to do this quickly... try typing "Show only selected Java element" there :)

Comment: @SamGoldberg I know it's been a while, but you can set a key binding to do this, but as of Oxygen, there isn't a default key binding set.

Answer (score 4):

`Declaration` in eclipse tell you about the declaration of the java object currently selected in the editor.

If you have selected a Class it will show the definition of the class and for an Object the line where the object was defined.