# Eclipse Implementation View

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, implementation, eclipse-3.6

Is there a notable plugin or a feature I am overlooking that allows an "Implementation view" similar to the "Declaration view" already available in Eclipse Helios? The code I am working with is plagued with interfaces and it would be infinitely useful to see what a method call does at a glance without toggling over to a new tab.

Note: I already have hyperlinking set up and use Ctrl+T extensively, what I am looking for is something like what you'd find by using `Window-> Show View-> Other -> Java -> Declaration`.

EDIT:

Example code:

```
public interface MyInterface{
  public void doSomething();
}

public class MyImplementation implements myInterface{
  public void doSomething{
    //Do something
  }
}

public class MyClass{
  public void someMethod(){
    MyImplementation impl = new MyImplementation();
    impl.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Placing the cursor on `doSomething()` in `MyClass.someMethod()` will display `public void doSomething();` in the Declaration view. What I would like to see is:

```
public void doSomething{
  //Do something
}
```

I understand that this would not work in the case of multiple possible implementations, yet neither would the hyperlinking (AKA Ctrl+Click) I mentioned earlier and Eclipse has no problems supporting that.

Comment: That mirrors the functionality of Ctrl+T, and as stated in the question, opens a new tab to view the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781817/2607904), there is a similar feature that allows you to achieve identical goals. You'll just have to navigate to `Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Editor > Only show the selected Java element` if you're running on a Mac, and `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Only show the selected Java element` if you're using a Windows computer, or possibly any other OS. I hope my answer satisfied you!

EDIT: You may be looking for this: `Window > Show View > Other > Java > Declaration`, specified [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0-200406251208/eclipse-news-part5-R3.html).

Comment: This limits the code shown on-screen to the method that is currently being worked on. Check out the declaration view and click around on a few methods to get a better idea of what I am looking for. I am looking for the same functionality offered by that view yet when clicking a method specified by an interface, it pulls the IMPLEMENTATION instead of the DECLARATION.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you completely, but you might be looking for this: Window > Show View > Other > Java > Declaration, specified here: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0-200406251208/eclipse-news-part5-R3.html

Comment: Yes, that is the droid I am looking for. Now as for what I am asking, please see the edit above.

Comment: That's unfortunately as long as you can get. It's happening because it's an interface. If you create something non-interface, it will most likely show you what you wish to see. You'll probably have to live with it. :(