# How can i find a given text witin "Declaration" tab in Eclipe?

Tags: eclipse

Ctrl + F does not work within "declaration" view ? how can i do to search  within this view ?

Eclipse declaration view
[image: eclipse declaration view]

Comment: What 'declaration tab'? What editor or perspective is this?

Comment: You can find more details about this view here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781399/what-is-eclipses-declaration-view-used-for

Comment: You can't search in that view. Use F3 to open the class in a normal editor and search in that.

Comment: Thank you, that's resolve perfectly my problem.